# network connection refused in putty while connecting pi

Tags: raspbian, ssh, putty

I'm able to ping successfully but the connection fails on port 22, IP address: 192.168.137.100 of Raspberry Pi model B+.

I checked `ipconfig` at the command prompt and entered ping of it, also tried `arp -a` but gives following:

```
Interface: 192.168.137.100 --- 0x12
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.137.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go to your settings menue on raspbian (upper left corner) and check if SSH is enabled.

Upper right corner -> configuration -> interfaces -> SSH -> enable

[image: config]

Alternativly, you can enable it as follows:
http://raspberrypiguide.de/howtos/ssh-zugriff-unter-raspbian-einrichten/

It is in German, but just follow the pictures